# Как ArrayList <Integer> заполнить с клавиатуры?

Tags: java, arraylist

Как `ArrayList <Integer>` заполнить с клавиатуры?

Comment: заполнить чем вы хотите?

Comment: нужен компьютер 1 штука, клавиатура 1 штука, arraylist  1 штука и примерно 5-7 лет совбодного времени

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Вот так можно](https://ideone.com/9cHCjG)

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList < Integer > mylist = new ArrayList < Integer > ();
while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    int i = scanner.nextInt();
    mylist.add(i);
}

for (int i = 0; i < mylist.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(mylist.get(i));
}
```

Вкладки input/output